# Redirect from IP that doesn't exist on a subnet to one that does

Tags: networking, routing

I have a device that connects to a 192.168.1.0/24 subnet. However this device then tries to fire a request to 192.168.50.200/24 (the 192.168.50.0/24 subnet does not exist) is it possible through forwarding or NAT to reroute these packets somewhere else?

```
192.168.1.44 -> 192.168.50.200/api/foo -> ??? -> 192.168.1.143/api/foo
```

I can get around this by expanding my subnet so that 192.168.50.200 can be included and then just manually change 192.168.1.143 to be 192.168.50.200.

However, I'd like to not expand my subnet. Are there anyways of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not something you can do through port forwarding (but can be done   through a type of NAT called DNAT)  and most routers wont support this through their GUI. If you are running something like dd-wrt you should be able to affect this at the command line. Ive not tested this but maybe something like

```
  iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING  -d 192.168.50.200 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.143
```

Comment: so this requires hairpinning, right? if thats the case, how did the packet end up incoming on the WAN? or will DNAT pick up the packet while exiting the WAN? I keep feeling like the WAN needs a route or something telling it to process traffic for .50. as incoming. otherwise wouldn't the packet just exit the WAN and go to its default gateway? not sure what I;m missing.

Comment: You raise a good point. My solution is likely incomplete because you would additionally need to nat the source IP address for hairpinning to work. (but none of this goes through the WAN port)

Comment: Not sure what hairpinning is and these requests are all done on LAN no WAN involved.

Comment: well, that's the thing. NAT is inherently a Router technology, and it sits between the WAN and the LAN, so if you want to use NAT to translate the IP for you, the traffic has to pass through the NAT. So one thing I can think of that you could try, is just adding 192.168.50.x IP addresses on both the boxes involved in the transaction. Your switch doesn't really care what your IPs are, so you can carve out a little network within your LAN, as long as there isn't a need for routing. you will likely need a route in both boxes for the .50. network. I **Think** it would work.

Comment: @FrankThomas I used the GUI to generate the following rules `-A VYATTA_DNAT -d 192.168.50.200/32 -i switch0 -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "NAT-1 tcp_udp" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.143` and `-A VYATTA_DNAT -d 192.168.50.200/32 -i switch0 -p udp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "NAT-1 tcp_udp" -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.143` but it's not working.

Comment: ok Vyatta huh. so you do have a rather sophisticated router. interesting. the UDP rule is unneeded if you only want 80/443. that said you will need to allow hairpinning and resolve the issue I raised with it going out to the wan public interface and back in, so it gets processed by the nat rule. Is this an actual multi-port enterprise router? if it is you could create a .50. network on one of the ports, and run another line from the .143 box to that port. then you wouldn't need to use NAT or anything else fancy.

Comment: What do you mean by boxes? For the sake of this example, I would only have access to the (one) router.

Comment: Its an Edgerouter X

Comment: yes and that you only have one router is the problem. if you had the ability to create an actual .50. network, this would be easy. by box I mean PCs/Servers.  PCs use "Routes" in their route table to determine where to send traffic. they more or less indicate how to reach a router, and which router you shoudl reach, based on the destination address. Edit: ok, good, the edgerouter x should have 5 router ports, so you can create a .50. network off one of them. nice. I like ubiquity as well.